# Apache IoTDB query returning duplicate data when one field has no data

Tags: apache-iotdb, iotdb

When one numeric field has no data, why do the other two fields returned duplicate data in Apache IoTDB?

Currently, I use Apache IoTDB Version 1.0.0 and there are three numeric field, cc1_tag1, cc1_tag2, and cc1_tag3. When I tried to query data in certain time range when cc1_tag3 has no data at all, cc1_tag1 and cc1_tag2 will return duplicate data (which they should not be). When cc1_tag3 has data, the query result will report normal. Does anyone know what's going on and how to fix it? Why do I feel like it's a bug?

Does anyone can deal this problem？ Help please.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known problem and has already been fixed in Apache IoTDB Version 1.0.1. However, you can upgrade directly to the newest version, Version 1.1.0 to prevent other known bugs from causing you execution problems.